# C conflicting types error without actually having conflicting types?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

So I declared the function in the .h file and to do that I just copied and pasted the function declaration and added a semicolon so I don't see where the error comes from.

Source:

```
struct node* remove(struct node* node, int key)
{
    
    if(search(root,removeMe)!=NULL){
        struct node* temp=search(root,removeMe);
        if(temp->left==NULL && temp->right==NULL)
        {
            temp=NULL;
            return node;
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

Header:

```
#ifndef PROJECT2_BST_H
#define PROJECT2_BST_H typedef struct node {
    int key;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right; }; struct node* insert(struct node* node, int key); void inorder(struct node *root);

//void quit(struct node *root); struct node* search(struct node* root,
int key);  struct node* remove(struct node* node, int key);

#endif //PROJECT2_IO_H }
```

Comment: With the header formatted as shown, the header should not compile at all.  Please make sure the code you show matches what you really have in your header.  I can guess, but I would probably guess wrong.

Comment: That header code looks like it was thrown in a blender. Can you straighten that out?

Comment: It's worth noting your `remove()` function doesn't actually remove things from the linked list, you're just changing a throw-away local variable that's a copy of a pointer, and if it did it would be leaking memory. It also presumes that `temp` is a valid pointer and goes ahead and dereferences it without checking first, which is undefined behaviour should `search` return inconsistent results or be within threaded code.

Comment: You also perform `search` twice, once throwing away the results, the second time capturing it. You should search once and capture it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `remove` is a standard library function, normally defined in `stdio.h` as

```
int remove (const char *__filename)
```

So I suggest you change the name of your function. Perhaps in this case you could add a prefix such as `node_` to each of your function names to prevent name collisions; so `node_remove`, `node_insert`, etc.